# I couldnt get jwt token from google

Tags: java, maven, jwt, token

First of all i take client_id and client_secret from google developer tools. I am writing an API automation and I need to automatically get the Google token after signing in with a Google email and password in the option to sign in with Google on a site(e.g: [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)).
First I added these dependencies to my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.10</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-oauth2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev157-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-jackson2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.6</version>
</dependency>
```

After i wrote these codes :

```
package JWTToken;


import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

public class JwtToken {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Google OAuth 2.0 
        String clientId = "519214871295-o8********3m9i75ao7mm.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        String clientSecret = "GOCSPX-*********7wKn5pXYZ";

        // Google OAuth 2.0 
        GoogleCredentials credentials = new GoogleCredentials.Builder()
                .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
                .build();

        String accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        System.out.println(accessToken);
    }
}
```

But `Builder()` has protected access in `com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.Builder`. How can i access it or any advice for me. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I've found [another way](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java) that would probably suit you better:

```
 /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
 private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
   // load client secrets
   GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
       new InputStreamReader(CalendarSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
   // set up authorization code flow
   GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
       httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
       Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
      .build();
   // authorize
   return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}
```

See that documentation for more information.

But basically you should better store you `clientId` and `clientSecret` in a JSON file to have it not in the source code.

With that you can build your `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` object and receive from that the `Credential`.

Comment: However, when I use it this way, It does not find the .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret) .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport()) .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory()) methods.